FCM version update for SDK
FCM version: 21.0.0 :
I was using FirebaseInstanceId along with FirebaseOptionsBuilder to receive notifcation on SDK side of the project.
Current docs say
Apps still using deprecated Instance ID APIs for token management should update all token logic to use the FCM APIs described here 
So after migrating to 24.0.1, it seems my project require google-service.json to receive cloud messaging. My question is why do we have to add this google-services.json file if we can fetching the details from the server and set it like below as per previous version.
 val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setGcmSenderId(firebaseConfig!!.GcmSenderId)
                .setApiKey(firebaseConfig.ApiKey)
                .setApplicationId(firebaseConfig.ApplicationId)
                .setStorageBucket(firebaseConfig.StorageBucket)
                .setProjectId(firebaseConfig.ProjectId)
                .setDatabaseUrl(firebaseConfig.DatabaseUrl)
                .build()

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "SDK")

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.w("Test", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.exception)
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }

            val token = task.result
            Log.d("Test", token)
        })

As soon as I make any change or remove the json file the project crashes. I have seen and read the previous threads 1 2 3 which suggests to put the google-service.json file on the client side and manage it from there, but I want to know why can't I use my previous approach with FirebaseOptions Builder or is there any other possible way to manage the notification on SDK part. Also, would it be a good idea to revert back to old version and keep it operating the same way?

Hey Preet! What happens if you remove the usage of com.google.gms.google-services from your gradle build file?

Thanks @karllindmark for your prompt response, upon removal of com.google.gms.google-services the following error is thrown at runtime
   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.projectName. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)`


After testing with logs, I see the default FirebaseApp from google-service.json is same as using with FirebaseOptions Builder. However, when calling the next line FirebaseMessaging, it's throwing the error. I checked my old code FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(app!!).instanceId.addOnCompleteListener { which used to take app as argument. However same thing is package-private in FirebaseMessaging Class FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app).token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->

As suspected, the issue occures when we are using the factory method of FirebaseApp. When the factory is replace with default FirebaseApp instance the code works without google-services.json file. Now the question remains that how can I use the factory/named instance which cannot be passed to FirebaseMessaging Class.
Works: FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options),
Doesn't work: FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "SDK")

RESOLVED: Rest can be solved from here

Good job! You should add your full solution as an answer to your own question so future visitors will be able to put it all together. :-) @Preet Patel

SOLUTION
The following code is an alternative to setup firebase clould messaging without google-service.json file.
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setGcmSenderId(firebaseConfig!!.GcmSenderId)
                .setApiKey(firebaseConfig.ApiKey)
                .setApplicationId(firebaseConfig.ApplicationId)
                .setStorageBucket(firebaseConfig.StorageBucket)
                .setProjectId(firebaseConfig.ProjectId)
                .setDatabaseUrl(firebaseConfig.DatabaseUrl)
                .build()

    val app: FirebaseApp? = try {
        // Attempt to get the existing FirebaseApp instance
        FirebaseApp.getInstance("SDK")
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        // If it doesn't exist, initialize it
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "SDK")
    }

    val firebaseMessaging = app?.get(FirebaseMessaging::class.java) as FirebaseMessaging
    firebaseMessaging.token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.w("LOG", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.exception)
            return@OnCompleteListener
        }

        // Get new FCM registration token
        val token = task.result
        Log.d("LOG", token)
    })

